# Kick out the user automatically when the same account logs in again?

Tags: java, sql-server, swing

Thanks for all your replies! Here is my code! Please give your comments!
I created a column to save the present status of USER

```
    ShareHelper.USER = nhanVien;//use static variable to save USER
                if (ShareHelper.USER.getStatus() == 0) {//first login -> change status from 0 to 1
                    DialogHelper.alert(this, "Đăng nhập thành công!");
                    nvd.updateStatus(1, nhanVien.getMaNV());
                    this.dispose();
                    EduSys edu = new EduSys();
                    edu.setVisible(true);
                } else if (ShareHelper.USER.getStatus() == 1) { //if someone logged before -> allow to login again
                    DialogHelper.alert(this, "Đăng nhập thành công!");
                    EduSys edu = new EduSys();
                    edu.setVisible(true);
                    nvd.updateStatus(2, nhanVien.getMaNV());//then update status to 2
                    this.dispose();
                }
```

And in MainFrame I use a thread to update the status consecutively

```
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {//use Thread to check if status change to 2-> someone logs in with same account
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                model.NhanVien nhanVien = nvd.findById(ShareHelper.USER.getMaNV());
                ShareHelper.USER = nhanVien;
                if (ShareHelper.USER.getStatus() == 2) {
                    DialogHelper.alert(EduSys.this, "Có người đã đăng nhập tài khoản này!");
                    ShareHelper.logoff();//log out the present session
                    nvd.updateStatus(1, ShareHelper.USER.getMaNV());//change status to 1 again
                    EduSys.this.dispose();
                    dn.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t1.start();
```

But I got a trouble! When I log in the second time, I got kicked in both previous session  and present session because Status has been changed to 2 by previous session then present session receives that value too. Can someone please help me to fix this! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so far.

Comment: why not just making it impossible for the application to start up a second time?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I agree here: your question is really too broad. We dont design solutions for you, we help with specific programming problems!

Comment: @Stultuske if someone forgot to log out then they cannot log in anywhere else!

Comment: @GhostCat Cause I can't find the way to solve it. I'll post my code soon! Thanks!

Comment: @samabcde Cause I can't find the way to solve it. I'll post my code soon! Thanks!

Comment: @TuanNguyen how is that? what I said would make it impossible for two users to login at one pc, not for one user not to login at several pc's (usually users tend to work on the same machines)

Comment: @Stultuske yeah I know. I made it before but it's not the best way because some one needs to use program anywhere they want ^.^

Comment: @TuanNguyen again: how would this be blocked by my suggestion? it would just be a start towards not being logged in twice. You'll need to server-side keep track of who is logged in, and you'll need to verify this on login. If there's already a session running: log-out. A more logical way would be to check for inactivity. The user has been inactive for ten minutes? log-out

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Simple approach. First create application level simple cache(a simple has map will work) which will maintain the status of the user. If the user Loggs in for first time create entry for the User with the Logged in value (i.e USER -> 1) .and Update the Field accordingly in DB. 
Now if the user tries to log in again Check in map for the entry if its already logged-in change the value in map as well as DB and kill all the session of that user

Thanks
TG